# Vagrant: install git using Chef

Tags: git, vagrant, chef-infra

I'm using a [Chef cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/git) to install Git in my Vagrant VM. Accordingly to the [default configuration](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/git/blob/master/attributes/default.rb), the cookbook should install Git 2.8.1, but instead I'm getting Git 1.9.1.

What would be the proper way of using Chef to install a more recent Git version? To keep the configuration simple, I would still like to use Cookbooks.

This is my configuration so far:

Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      chef.add_recipe "git"
  end   
end
```

metadata.rb:

```
name             'vagrant-example'

recipe 'git', 'Installs git'
```

Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.chef.io"

metadata

cookbook "git"
```

Berksfile.lock:

```
DEPENDENCIES
  git
  vagrant-example
    path: .
    metadata: true

GRAPH
  build-essential (6.0.3)
    compat_resource (>= 12.10)
    mingw (>= 1.1)
    seven_zip (>= 0.0.0)
  chef_handler (1.4.0)
  compat_resource (12.10.7)
  dmg (2.4.0)
  git (4.6.0)
    build-essential (>= 0.0.0)
    dmg (>= 0.0.0)
    windows (>= 0.0.0)
    yum-epel (>= 0.0.0)
  mingw (1.2.4)
    compat_resource (>= 0.0.0)
    seven_zip (>= 0.0.0)
  seven_zip (2.0.1)
    windows (>= 1.2.2)
  vagrant-example (0.0.0)
  windows (1.44.1)
    chef_handler (>= 0.0.0)
  yum (3.11.0)
  yum-epel (0.7.0)
    yum (>= 3.6.3)
```

Output from Vagrant up:

```
==> default: Installing Cookbook Gems:
==> default: Compiling Cookbooks...
==> default: Converging 1 resources
==> default: Recipe: git::package
==> default:   
==> default: * git_client[default] action install
==> default:     
==> default: * apt_package[default :create git] action install
==> default: [2016-08-14T01:11:04+00:00] INFO: apt_package[default :create git] installed git at 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3
==> default:       - install version 1:1.9.1-1ubuntu0.3 of package git
==> default: 
==> default:   
==> default: 
==> default: 
==> default: [2016-08-14T01:11:04+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 13.492574359 seconds
```

I even tried specifying the version using Chef attributes in the Vagrantfile, but it also did not work:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      chef.add_recipe "git"

      chef.json = {
            "git" => {
              "version" => "2.8.1"
            }
       }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git::default` recipe installs from your distro packages which for Ubuntu Trusty is 1.9.1. You can use the `git::source` recipe to force it to compile from source which can install any version.